# Как завершить процесс зная его название?

Tags: delphi

Пробую такой код:

```
WinExec(PANsiChar('TASKKILL /F /IM DiChecker_1.8.exe *32'), SW_HIDE);
```

но выдаёт такую вешь:
       [image: img1]

при условии что в диспечере задач процесс прописан так:
[image: img2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже сам разобрался.Решил проблему через `KillTask('DiСhecker_1.8.exe');`

Answer (score 1):

***32** - это фича диспетчера задач, показывающая, что процесс 32-битный.
Поэтому твой код можно поправить следующим образом:

```
WinExec(PANsiChar('TASKKILL /F /IM DiChecker_1.8.exe *32'), SW_HIDE);
```

Или обойтись без запуска дополнительного процесса:

```
bool KillProcessByName(char* name)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE hProcess = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry = {0};
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    processEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(hSnapshot, &processEntry);
    do 
    {
        if (_stricmp(processEntry.szExeFile, name) == 0)
        {
            pid = processEntry.th32ProcessID;
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, pid);
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &processEntry));
    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    if (hProcess == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return false;
    }
    return (TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0) != 0)
}
```